# ASIHTTP Request

Tags: iphone

Please any one know abhout how to send request and send a file in ASIHTTP with some parameters my code is bellow i am not able to send file

```
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.kuwait.tt/demo_radioapps/radio_mobile/adduserrequest.php?program_id=3&user_name=abhishek&user_email_id=abhi@tets.com&audiofile=review.caf&mode=AddRequest"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];
[request addData:tempData withFileName:@"review.caf" andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"audiofile"];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: It's bad form to send requests synchronously. You should send it asynchronously to prevent the UI from being locked up.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: `[request setData:tempData withFileName:@"review.caf" andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"audiofile"];`

// Add the contents of an NSData object to the request and you can specify the content-type and file name

```
- (void)addData:(id)data withFileName:(NSString *)fileName andContentType:(NSString *)contentType forKey:(NSString *)key
```

// Add the contents of an NSData object to the request, clearing any others with the same key
and you can specify the content-type and file name

```
- (void)setData:(id)data withFileName:(NSString *)fileName andContentType:(NSString *)contentType forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

perhaps you can validate the success of the request with

```
if ([request responseStatusCode] == 200) {
            NSLog (@"Response status code: %i", [request responseStatusCode]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working function which i have used in my application , please check if it helps:

```
 - (void)uploadAudioFile:(NSString  *)audioPath{
        NSURL *audiourl=[NSURL URLWithString:audioPath];
    NSData *audioData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audiourl.path];
            @try {
        NSString *strURL = @"http://www.abc.com/data/default.aspx";
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        request= [request initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];
        [request setPostValue:[Settings UserName] forKey:@"lblUsername"];
        [request setPostValue:[Settings Password] forKey:@"lblpassword"];
        [request addData:audioData withFileName:@"audio.caf" andContentType:@"audio/x-caf" forKey:@"filMyFile"];

        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"Request Completed");             
            [self requestFinished:request];
        }];

        //if request failed
        [request setFailedBlock:^{
            [self requestFailed:request];
            NSLog(@"request Failed: %@",[request error]); 
        }];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception name and reson is %@  -------  %@",exception.name, exception.reason);   
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finalyy of upload audio");
    }   
}


 - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {    
     NSLog(@"requestFinished");

 }

 - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
       NSLog(@"requestFailed");

 }
```